# Mass Diffusion Equation (Fick's Second Law)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, ordinary-differential-equations

Solving the Mass Diffusion Equation $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = D_m\frac{\partial ^2 \rho}{\partial x^2}$$ for $$\rho (x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_mt}}f\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{D_mt}}\right)$$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \rho(x,t) dx = M$$ where M is the total mass of the diffusing particles, I obtained a differential equation of the form $$2f''(u) + uf'(u) + f(u) = 0$$ Above, $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{D_mt}}$. How do I analytically solve this differential equation to find the functional form of $f(u)$?

Comment: Use Mathematica.

Comment: i don’t see how you get this differential equation?. To solve this differential equation i will try this ansatz $\rho=w(t) v(x)$

Comment: Mathematica gives me the solution, alright, but I was curious if we have a way to analytically arrive at that solution.

Comment: Secondly, ρ=w(t)v(x) is basically the "Separation of Variables" method and is perfectly fine. But the above question specifically mentions the form of ρ that is to be assumed.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: Hints. You can express this equation as $\frac{d}{du}$ of something $=0$: the first term on the left is already of this form, and the other two terms *together* can be recognised as having this form. Therefore, you can integrate the equation once. There will be a constant of integration $C$, which you can determine by considering the limits $u\rightarrow\pm\infty$ (which, physically, corresponds to $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ at constant $t$). $C$ should be zero. Then, the resulting equation can again be arranged into a form which you can integrate directly. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

$$2f''(u) + uf'(u) + f(u) = 2f''+(uf)'=0$$so
$$2f'+uf=C$$From the boundary conditions, C = 0.  So, $$\frac{f'}{f}=-\frac{u}{2}$$The solution to this differential equation is:
$$f=Ae^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}$$where A is a constant of integration.  So,
$$\rho=\frac{A}{\sqrt{D_mt}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}$$To determine A, all you need to do is satisfy the condition $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rho du}=\frac{M}{\sqrt{D_mt}}$$or$$A\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}du=M$$